# Jar files using Ant

Tags: ant

Ok, so in order to find an easier way to build jar files I took a users advice and tried to go the Apache Ant way.
I am going step by step through this tutorial http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html#prepare

Everything is fine until I get to the line:

```
jar cfm build\jar\HelloWorld.jar myManifest -C build\classes
```

I get a long message right after that line that goes something like this...

"Useage: jar {ctxui}[vfm0me] [jar-file] [manifest-file] [entry-point] [-C dir] files..."  Then it lists Options.

I am trying to figure out where I am going wrong as I thought following a tutorial word for word file for file directory for directory would be simple.  **Am I doing something wrong or is the tutorial missing something??**

Answer (score 1):

In the tutorial, I see

> jar cfm build\jar\HelloWorld.jar myManifest -C build\classes .

Are you missing the "." at the end possibly?

Comment: Izodness, mark the answer as correct (tick it), because the question still appears under "unanswered" tab.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you missed dot

```
jar cfm build\jar\HelloWorld.jar myManifest -C build\classes .
```

Comment: A space then "."  Sometimes it's the smallest things that really get you frustrated.  Thanks, but could someone explain the purpose of the " ." ?

Comment: Here dot (.) represents all classes under the classes folder which included in the jar

Comment: So since I have a single class file build-->classes-->oata-->HelloWorld.class can I just type that into the console like...

`jar cfm build\jar\HelloWorld.jar myManifest -C build\classes\oata\HelloWorld.class`

Comment: Thanks. Im starting to understand it.